# vagrant で GUIなど標準のパッケージを含む ubuntu 14.04のboxは公開されていますか？

Tags: vagrant

Windowsにvagrantで仮想環境のUbuntu14.04を構築したいのですが、
サーバーのテスト用途ではなくDesktop環境なども公式で配布されてる標準のもののようにしたく思っています。

普通にisoファイルを使ってVirtualboxにUbuntuのインストールを行っても良いのですが、vagrant経由でできれば使い回しがしやすいため、そのためのboxを探しています。

[こちら](https://vagrantcloud.com/janihur/boxes/ubuntu-1404-desktop)にそれらしいものがあったのですが、`vagrant init janihur/ubuntu-1404-desktop`, `vagrant up`するとファイルがないらしくダウンロードが行われません。

`veewee`というものを使えば box の生成ができるようですが、これを用いて作るしかないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

記載されているbox、確かにダウンロードができませんね。

[shockwavemk/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64-dev | Atlas by HashiCorp](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/shockwavemk/boxes/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64-dev)

64bit版でそれらしいものを見つけましたが、どうでしょうか？(有効そうなことは確認しましたが、手元だとダウンロードに1時間半くらいかかるみたいです)

Comment: CPUがIntelを使っているためAMDのものが動くか心配だったのですが、正常に起動まで確認できました。どうやら公式のパッケージとは違う部分が多いようですが、自分の目的には十分な状態ですのでこれを使っていこうと思います。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 良かったです。boxファイルは質問にも書かれている通り自作することも可能ですし、あるいは最小構成のboxをchefと組み合わせることもできます(vagrantにクックブックのリポジトリパスなど設定を書くことで管理もそれほど難しくありません)ので、最初から決まったパッケージのみ入れたい場合はそちらも試されると良いかもしれません。